# We have 5 [farming] tags: what to do about it?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[This new question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/316/which-crops-involve-the-least-collateral-harm-when-grown-harvested) created a farming tag.  I was fairly sure we had one already, because I remember fixing a typo in one.  However, it turns out we have *5*.

- [Which crops involve the least collateral harm when grown/harvested?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/316/which-crops-involve-the-least-collateral-harm-when-grown-harvested) - [farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming)
- [How to avoid being part of the slaughter of cockerels on the free-range egg farms?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/193/how-to-avoid-being-part-of-the-slaughter-of-cockerels-on-the-free-range-egg-farm) - [poultry-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poultry-farming)
- [What area is most favorable to subsistence gardening for a vegan diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/287/what-area-is-most-favorable-to-subsistence-gardening-for-a-vegan-diet-) [subsistence-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsistence-farming) (FWIW this was the one I edited, subsistence was spelled wrong. Simple fix.)
- [Can a modern diet be vegan, organic and sustainable?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/292/can-a-modern-diet-be-vegan-organic-and-sustainable) - [sustainable-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable-farming)
- [How can grazing land be converted to contribute to feeding a vegan world?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-grazing-land-be-converted-to-contribute-to-feeding-a-vegan-world) - [commerical-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerical-farming)

I'm not saying any of these questions are off-topic, I haven't even looked at them much yet.

However, we probably don't need 5 distinct tags. I'd be in favor of keeping [farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming) and maybe [commercial-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial-farming), or maybe keeping [subsistence-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsistence-farming) and [commercial-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial-farming) (because I think most people on this site who farm do it to eat, not to sell.

Should we merge, burninate, synonymize some?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's burn them all except [commercial-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial-farming) (that could have some synonyms or be a synonym maybe) and [subsistence-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsistence-farming) since it should be possible to put all questions in one or the other.

A catch-all [farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming) seems like it would end up defining too little, while [poultry-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poultry-farming) seems too specific.

[sustainable-farming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable-farming) should be covered by a combination of one of the farming tags and something like [environment](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment) or [sustainability](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainability). (we already have the former)

Comment: Tags once created can't be deleted but synonyms can be created.

Comment: @SreeCharan we can cause them to be deleted by untagging all the questions - I destroy a lot of tags on Ask Ubuntu :D

Comment: But that's a lot of work and time consuming. There is only way to delete tags - they  automatically get deleted when not in use for a long time. But the above tags seems useless to me.

Comment: I don't mind burning useless tags that way @SreeCharan if it needs doing I will do it. Tags with questions will never be deleted - untagging is the only way. Exactly which tags seem useless? Do you agree with this answer?

Comment: IMO Creating a separate tag every time for every type of farming is unnecessary. That is what I meant  If there is a closer tag, then we should adjust with that. New tags should be created only when no tag is close to the topic of question. +1.